# how to collect data from a stream and write a response in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, stream

I am new to node.js and to it's environment so I am having problems when I want to make a server that listens for incoming data from a socket. 
The problem is I am having trouble working with streams in node.js. I listen for incoming data and usually i get 3-4 requests sent on the socket. The problem is I want to write and after that exit the code or something.
How do I know when the client has finished sending all his data. I check for a size param in the json received now, but I am not sure if it is a good idea. Basically I want to handle all the data he sent and after that send 1 response, how I did it now it sends the same response many times.

This is a part of my code for example and testing purpose:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(sock) {
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        var string = data.toString()
            ,json = JSON.parse(string);

        if (json.size > 50) {
            sock.write(JSON.stringify(
                {"success" : "OK"}
            ); 
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: there should be an "end" event you can listen for on the socket. I've never used the net module though so could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(sock) {
  sock.on('data', function(data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data.toString());
    // Probably want to do something special here
  });
  sock.on('end', function() {
    // Server disconnected
    sock.write(JSON.stringify({ success: 'OK' });
  });
});
```